# Jar files empty when copying with gradle

Tags: gradle, jar

I've got a couple of subprojects in my root project.

```
| - root
 \ 
   | - subproject_a
   | - subproject_b
   | - subproject_c
```

The gradle file in subproject_c copies the jars generated from subproject_a and subproject_b into its own libs folder for compilation.

The files are copied (that is, the names of the jar files show up in subproject_c's libs folder) but they are entirely empty.

Here's the portion of subproject_c's gradle file which does the copying.

```
task copyJars(type: Copy) {
    rootProject.subprojects.each {
        from("${it.projectDir}/libs") {
            include '*.jar'
        }
        into "{projectDir}/libs"
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems odd to me that the jars generated by your subprojects are in their respective `libs` folders. How do you put them there? Are you sure that you are copying the correct jar files?

Comment: @lukegv The jars are created by the gradle files in the respective subprojects. I believe they're needed for testing and so are generated in the subprojects' lib folder rather than in subproject_c's libs folder directly, but I can double check. Subproject_c's folder is populated with jar files with the correct names as those found in subproject_a and subproject_a, however the jar files are empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm responding for the sake of those who may run across this in the future. This ended up working for me.

```
 task copyJars() { 
    rootProject.subprojects.each { 
        File fileProj = new File("{it.projectDir}", "libs");
        if(fileProj.exists() && fileProj.absolutePath != "${projectDir}/libs") { 
            copy {
                from(fileProj)
                into "${projectDir}/libs"
                include "*.jar"
             }  
        }
    }
 }
```